# Перенаправление на веб-сайт при подключении к вай фай

Tags: wifi

Как настроить перенаправление на указанный url всех клиентов сети, такое возможно?
Мне необходимо перенаправлять всех людей которые подключились к wi-fi магазина на сайт магазина.

P.S. Есть такая тема что при неуплате тарифа ежемесячно вылезает страница что я не оплатил трафик, может это как-то связано или поможет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это называется [**Captive portal**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal)

Для этого требуется WiFi оборудование с поддержкой **captive portal**, например что-то от Кuckus, Cisco, Aruba.

Так же это вполне можно настроить с **openwrt**

Comment: Я могу установить прошивку openwrt на свой роутер,можете объяснить как это настроить?

Comment: Извините,  но я сам не имел дела с роутерами на openwrt, но для реализации вроде, как можно использовать пакеты `nodogsplash` или `wifidog`

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за помощь